# Regex: account@domain (active directory)

Tags: regex

Something like testuser@test.local should be a match. The regex I use is:

```
\w[\w\.\- ]*$/@/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{0,61}[a-zA-Z]
```

What did I miss?

It's not like an E-Mail because it can be many sublevels in the domain e.g. test.local.country.city.street

Comment: `\w[\w\.\- ]*@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{0,61}[a-zA-Z]` would match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Are you sure that complex names and domains of level above second should be considered incorrect?

Comment: @Gangnus example?

Comment: @Thypari    pete.gangnus'at'mydomain.publicfreedomain.countrydomain

Comment: `$/@/^` can never match. No string has characters after the end of the string (or before the beginning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also define, where in the text that address can appear. But if the address is on a separate line, then:

```
^[\w]+\@[\w]+\.[^\d\W]+$
```

The test is [here](https://regex101.com/r/lbYJgz/1).

If you want to accept complex names and domains of level above second, too, then:

```
^[\w]+(\.[\w]+)*\@[\w]+(\.[\w]+)*\.[^\d\W]+$
```